# Swift app crashes after signing up and making a request

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3

App using a Rider and a Driver.  When signing up for an account as a Rider and then requesting a ride from the driver, the app crashes.  But if the rider has an account or signs up and logs out and then logs into app, the rider is able to request a ride without crashing the app.

**Sign Up Action**

```
   @IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let usernameTxt = usersnameTextField.text
    let cellTxt = cell.text

    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text,
        (email.characters.count > 0 && password.characters.count > 0 && (usernameTxt?.characters.count)! > 0 && (cellTxt?.characters.count)! > 0) {

        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.userImageView.image!, 0.8)

        rAuthService.instance.signUp(email, usersname: usernameTxt!, password: password, cell: cellTxt!, data: data!) { (error, data) in


            if error != nil {
                self.alertTheUser(title: "Login Error", message: "Unable to Create User")

               //
            } else if FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser != nil {

                rRydeHandler.Instance.rider = self.emailTextField.text!

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Rider", bundle: nil)
                let tabBar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! UITabBarController
                self.present(tabBar, animated: true, completion: nil)

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.RIDER_SEGUE, sender: nil)
            }
        }

    } else {
        self.alertTheUser(title: "Email and Password Required", message: "Please enter a valid email & password")
    }

} // signUpAction func
```

**rAuthService.instance.signUp-- EDITED**

```
    // 1 ... Creating the User (Sign Up)

func signUp(_ email: String, usersname: String, password: String, cell: String, data: Data!, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password,  completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {

            // Create a change request
            let changeRequest = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.profileChangeRequest();              changeRequest?.displayName = usersname

            // Commit profile changes to server
            changeRequest?.commitChanges() { (error) in


                if error != nil {

                    return
                }
            }

            // Show error to user
            self.handleFirebaseErrors(err: error as! NSError, loginHandler: loginHandler)

        } else { // success creating user

            if user?.uid != nil { // if there is a valid user id 

                // Store user to database
                self.setUserInfo(user, usersname: usersname, email: email, password: password, cell: cell, data: data!)

                // Log In the user
                self.login(email: email, password: password, loginHandler: loginHandler)
            }
        }
    })

}
```

**Request Ryde**

```
    // ... Request Ryde
func requestRyde(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, destLat: Double, destLong: Double, currentAddress: String, destAddress: String) {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    currUserid = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
    currUsername = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.displayName)!

    let newRequest = RideRequest(userId: currUserid, username: currUsername, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, destLat: destLat, destLong: destLong, currentAddress: currentAddress, destAddress: destAddress, active: true)

    ref.child("drivers").child("RideRequests").child(currUsername).setValue(newRequest.toAnyObject())

} // request ryde func
```

**error when app crashes - **

[image: error]

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I tried putting in the login() function after signUp() but nothing seems to work.

**Login**

```
func login(email: String, password: String, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
                self.handleFirebaseErrors(err: error as! NSError, loginHandler: loginHandler)
        } else {
            loginHandler?(nil, nil)
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: @Mungbeans Yes, I did, but I don't understand if I am signing up, it then should be logging in the user, according to my code, but it is not.

Comment: Still no result - put in change request but still getting a crash at: currUsername = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.displayName)! - Edited signUp() in post

Comment: can anyone offer any assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to find out how to allow persist login and seem to fix this issue instead.

To fix this problem, set user defaults for username and password, then once registered or signed up, the user is then directed back to login screen to login.

**@IBAction fund signUpAction()**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.emailTextField.text, forKey: "emailTextField")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.passwordTextField.text, forKey: "passwordTextField")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                // switch to Login Page

                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Sign Up is complete, You can now Log In!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                myAlert.addAction(ok)
                self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps someone else ...

Answer (score 0):

When u signed up u didn't setup profileChangeRequest to add displayName or photoURL, so your displayName is null.

```
func signUp(_ email: String, usersname: String, password: String, cell: String, data: Data!, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password,  completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {

// Create a change request
        let changeRequest = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.profileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.displayName = username

            // Commit profile changes to server
            changeRequest?.commitChanges() { (error) in


              if let error = error {

                return
              }
            // Show error to user
            self.handleFirebaseErrors(err: error as! NSError, loginHandler: loginHandler)

        } else { // success creating user

            if user?.uid != nil { // if there is a valid user id 

                // Store user to database
                self.setUserInfo(user, usersname: usersname, email: email, password: password, cell: cell, data: data!)

                // Log In the user
                self.login(email: email, password: password, loginHandler: loginHandler)
            }
        }
    })

} // Sign Up func
```

Comment: Updated answer, if u need more explanation im happy to assist.

Comment: Plz post your signup method and i will complete entire answer, otherwise i will use ur signin u posted and add changeRequest just for the sake of demonstating.

Comment: Sign Up method is in post: rAuthService.instance.signUp and also the @IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: AnyObject)

Comment: Yeah i saw that, here u have it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135472/discussion-between-aragunz-and-lizg).